# android autocomplete renders as blank list in portrait mode

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

I have a normal autocomplete:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView 
android:id="@+id/autocomplete_names"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/namesauto_prompt"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:completionThreshold="2"/>
```

...

```
AutoCompleteTextView nameinp = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_names);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
nameinp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I won't bother showing the names list, because it which works fine on my tablet running ICS, both in landscape and portrait modes. In landscape on my phone (Gingerbread) it does OK - the names appear the same way that autosuggest for texting does. But in portrait mode it just renders a blank listview beneath the autocomplete input. Any ideas why?

***UPDATE***

So, having played around with it, I notice that my list is there, it's just that it's white text on a white background (kind of hard to read). I can set my

```
android:popupBackground
```

to whatever color I like (dark gray is a contender at the moment) but I can't see a way to change the text color for the popup (or dropdown as it were), nor do I really understand why it's white in the first place...

Comment: try to add android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" in your manifest first

Comment: do I just add that entire line? because it doesn't seem to do anything. Something else weird I noticed: when I tap on the blank list (and it flashes blue) you can see the text "underneath", and that value gets entered into the input box?!? it's as if there's something sitting on top of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the problem of this issue, because even I faced this issue with `AutoCompleteTextView`. I found a workaround for this.
What you can do is set a custom xml in the `ArrayAdapter` that will have the `TextView` color set to **black**.

The custom `TextView` file `my_custom_textview.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:ellipsize="marquee" />
```

And set this xml in your `ArrayAdapter`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.my_custom_textview, names);
nameinp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this helps you..